# Glass (XE10) not recognized as running android device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-gdk

When connected, the Google Glass shows up as **"Android Composite ADB Interface"** under Android Device in my Device Manager.

In Eclipse (ADT), the Google Glass is in the **DDMS with status "online."**

The snippet added to my "android_winusb.inf" file under both x86 and amd64 in the ADT Bundle is as follows (this is the location used for the manual driver update):

```
;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

When I run a project with Build Target **Glass Development Kit preview** as an Android Application, the Glass does not appear as a running Android Device.

When running the command "adb devices" in the command window in the directory of where adb is (in platform-tools in the ADB bundle) there is a device listed.

I am operating on Windows 7.

Not sure what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

**EDIT: This problem only persists with the specific Glass I was using. This Glass is version XE10 and has actually been experiencing many problems. Another glass with version XE17.2 (up to date as of 5/21/14) was able to connect and load android projects with the above configurations.**

Comment: I would recommend updated to the current XE level (at the time of this post, that is XE17.2 .. like your other successfully seen Google Glass). Is there some reason you want to remain "down level"?

Comment: There was a problem with the actual Glass device that prevented it from auto update. This problem also happened to be the root of the problem as to why I couldn't setup my development environment perfectly.

Comment: After calling the helpful Glass support team I was able to fix the device and no longer have any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documenting resolution process in case others run into something similar.]

When Google Glass will not upgrade "automatically" when on WiFi and plugged in, the best resolution process is to call 800-GLASSXE for help .. as the original person with the problem did here.